# How to make a posted at (time), in laravel 4

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making my web site in Laravel 4 and I have the `created_at` & `updated_at` fields in the table. I want to make a news system that gives me how much time has passed since the post has been made.

```
|    name    |    text    |        created_at        |      updated_at     |
| __________ | __________ | ________________________ | ___________________ |
| news name  | news_text  |   2013-06-12 11:53:25    | 2013-06-12 11:53:25 |
```

I want to show something like:

> -created 5 minutes ago
>
> -created 5 months ago

if the post is older than 1 month

> -created at Nov 5 2012

Comment: Cool story. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using [Carbon](https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon). Laravel already comes with it as a dependency, so there is no need to add it yours.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// ...

// If more than a month has passed, use the formatted date string
if ($new->created_at->diffInDays() > 30) {
    $timestamp = 'Created at ' . $new->created_at->toFormattedDateString();

// Else get the difference for humans
} else {
    $timestamp = 'Created ' $new->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

---

As requested, I'll give an example of full integration, on how I think would be the better way to do it. First, I assume I might use this on several different places, several different views, so the best would be to have that code inside your model, so that you can conveniently call it from anywhere, without any hassle.

**Post.php**

```
class News extends Eloquent {

    public $timestamps = true;

    // ...

    public function formattedCreatedDate() {
        ìf ($this->created_at->diffInDays() > 30) {
            return 'Created at ' . $this->created_at->toFormattedDateString();
        } else {
            return 'Created ' . $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in your view files, you'd simply do `$news->formattedCreatedDate()`. Example:

```
<div class="post">
    <h1 class="title">{{ $news->title }}</h1>
    <span class="date">{{ $news->forammatedCreatedDate() }}</span>
    <p class="content">{{ $news->content }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you flesh out this answer more to indicate how you would incorporate this on the view level?

Answer (score 4):

Require Carbon:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

And use it:

```
$user = User::find(2);

echo $user->created_at->diffForHumans( Carbon::now() );
```

You should get this:

```
19 days before
```

Comment: I don't believe you have to pass the `Carbon::now()`